# Fitting custom functions to data

Tags: charts, curve-fitting, libreoffice-calc, data-fitting, trendline

I have a series of data, for example:

```
0.767838478
0.702426493
0.733858228
0.703275979
0.651456058
0.62427187
0.742353261
0.646359026
0.695630431
0.659101665
0.598786652
0.592840135
0.59199059
```

which I know fits best to an equation of the form:

```
y=ae^(b*x)+c
```

[image: Formula]

How can I fit the custom function to this data?

[Similar question](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/20662/calc-custom-trend-line-equation/) had been already asked on LibreOffice forum without a proper answer. I would appreciate if you could help me know how to do this. Preferably answers applying to any custom function rather than workarounds to this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

There are  multiple possible solutions for this. But one approach would be the following:

For determining the `a`and `b` in the trend line function `y = a*e^(b*x)` there are solutions using native `Calc` functions (`LINEST`, `EXP`, `LN`).

So we could the `y = a*e^(b*x)+c` taking as `y-c= a*e^(b*x)` and so if we are knowing `c`, the solution for `y = a*e^(b*x)` could be taken too. How to know c? One approach is described in [Exponential Curve Fitting](http://www.davdata.nl/math/expfitting.html). There approximation of b, a and then c are made.

I have the main part of the delphi code from [Exponential Curve Fitting : source listing](http://www.davdata.nl/math/expfitting/explisting.html) translated to `StarBasic` for `Calc`. The part of the fine tuning of `c` is not translated until now. To-Do for you as professional and enthusiast programmers.

Example:

[image]

Data:

```
x   y
0   0.767838478
1   0.702426493
2   0.733858228
3   0.703275979
4   0.651456058
5   0.62427187
6   0.742353261
7   0.646359026
8   0.695630431
9   0.659101665
10  0.598786652
11  0.592840135
12  0.59199059
```

Formulas:

`B17`: `=EXP(INDEX(LINEST(LN($B$2:$B$14),$A$2:$A$14),1,2))`

`C17`: `=INDEX(LINEST(LN($B$2:$B$14),$A$2:$A$14),1,1)`

`y = a*e^(b*x)` is also the function used for the chart's trend line calculation.

`B19`: `=INDEX(TRENDEXPPLUSC($B$2:$B$14,$A$2:$A$14),1,1)`

`C19`: `=INDEX(TRENDEXPPLUSC($B$2:$B$14,$A$2:$A$14),1,2)`

`D19`: `=INDEX(TRENDEXPPLUSC($B$2:$B$14,$A$2:$A$14),1,3)`

Code:

```
function trendExpPlusC(rangey as variant, rangex as variant) as variant

 'get values from ranges
 redim x(ubound(rangex)-1) as double
 redim y(ubound(rangex)-1) as double
 for i = lbound(x) to ubound(x)
  x(i) = rangex(i+1,1)
  y(i) = rangey(i+1,1)
 next

 'make helper arrays
 redim dx(ubound(x)-1) as double
 redim dy(ubound(x)-1) as double
 redim dxyx(ubound(x)-1) as double
 redim dxyy(ubound(x)-1) as double
 for i = lbound(x) to ubound(x)-1
  dx(i) = x(i+1) - x(i)
  dy(i) = y(i+1) - y(i)
  dxyx(i) = (x(i+1) + x(i))/2
  dxyy(i) = dy(i) / dx(i)
 next

 'approximate b
 s = 0
 errcnt = 0
 for i = lbound(dxyx) to ubound(dxyx)-1
  on error goto errorhandler
  s = s + log(abs(dxyy(i+1) / dxyy(i))) / (dxyx(i+1) - dxyx(i))
  on error goto 0
 next
 b = s / (ubound(dxyx) - errcnt)

 'approximate a
 s = 0
 errcnt = 0
 for i = lbound(dx) to ubound(dx)
  on error goto errorhandler
  s = s + dy(i) / (exp(b * x(i+1)) - exp(b * x(i)))
  on error goto 0
 next
 a = s / (ubound(dx) + 1 - errcnt)

 'approximate c 
 s = 0
 errcnt = 0
 for i = lbound(x) to ubound(x)
  on error goto errorhandler
  s = s + y(i) - a * exp(b * x(i))
  on error goto 0
 next
 c = s / (ubound(x) + 1 - errcnt)

 'make y for (y - c) = a*e^(b*x)
 for i = lbound(x) to ubound(x)
  y(i) = log(abs(y(i) - c))
 next

 'get a and b from LINEST for (y - c) = a*e^(b*x)
 oFunctionAccess = createUnoService( "com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess" )
 args = array(array(y), array(x))
 ab = oFunctionAccess.CallFunction("LINEST", args)

 if a < 0 then a = -exp(ab(0)(1)) else a = exp(ab(0)(1))

 b = ab(0)(0)

 trendExpPlusC = array(a, b, c)

exit function

errorhandler:
 errcnt = errcnt + 1
 resume next

end function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm gonna look into your code. but do you have any idea why this is a not already a feature in Calc?

Comment: @Foad: This is a not a feature in Calc because there is not one unique solution for  `a`, `b` and `c`. You told you are able to solving this with other software, Maxima, Python, GnuPlot.. What values are those other software providing for `a`, `b` and `c`? I suspect not the same as this solution. But at least all those the same?

Comment: Well, TBH I said I'm able not that I have done it :) I'm gonna do it and come back here to report. But it could be a great idea to ask this feature anyway.

Comment: I tried to find the fit in gnuplot but it was not able to find initially. Then with a little bit of cheating I assigned initial values and it did find a fit. but a bad one. I thin the data I have provided in the OP are not a good example. Maybe I should do something like [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and then provide some better sample data here.

Comment: as promised I implemented the fitting in Gnuplot and python. I used an slightly different dataset (embarrassingly enough I had forgot to mention the x values in my OP). of course I had to set initial values in both otherwise the solver would return errors. Ironically I used Calc to calculate these initial values. You may see the code here in this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/da7dab3a75f8a9cab275473230264a4c)

Answer (score 0):

The formula **y = be<sup>ax</sup>** is the [exponential regression equation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Trend_Lines#The_exponential_regression_equation) for LibreOffice chart trend lines.

[image: exponential equation chart]

Comment: The question references an equation with an offset parameter (named c) which is not in the documentation you linked to. I have this equation - including the offset term - available for fitting on my online curve and surface fitting web site, the link is http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/Exponential/Exponential%20With%20Offset/ if the OP cannot find another way to fit the data for this specific equation, this might be of some help.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks a lot for pointing out the issue with the answer. I am able to fit the data with other software, Maxima, Python, GnuPlot... but I want to do it right in the LibreOffice Calc as it is way more convenient for me.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice exports all settings
All the settings of LibreOffice, all in the LibreOffice folder.

> C:\Users\a←When installing the operating system, the name
>   entered.\AppData←File Manager ~ "Hidden project" to open, the AppData
>   folder will be displayed.\Roaming\LibreOffice

Back up the LibreOffice folder, when reinstalling, put the LibreOffice folder in its original place.

> **Note:**
>   1. If the installation is preview edition, because the name of preview edition is LibreOfficeDev, so the LibreOfficeDev folder will be
>   displayed.
>   2. Formal edition can be installed together with preview edition, if both formal edition and preview edition are installed, LibreOffice
>   folder and LibreOfficeDev folder will be displayed.
>   3. To clear all settings, just delete the LibreOffice folder, then open the program, a new LibreOffice folder will be created.

LibreOffice exports a single toolbar I made
Common path

> C:\Users\a←When installing the operating system, the name
>   entered.\AppData←File Manager ~ "Hidden project" to open, the AppData
>   folder will be
>   displayed.\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\config\soffice.cfg\modules\Please
>   connect the branch path of the individual software below.

**Branch path**

```
\modules\StartModule\toolbar\The "Start" toolbar I made is placed here.

\modules\swriter\toolbar\The "writer" toolbar I made is placed here.

\modules\scalc\toolbar\The "calc" toolbar I made is placed here.

\modules\simpress\toolbar\The "impress" toolbar I made is placed here.

\modules\sdraw\toolbar\The "draw" toolbar I made is placed here.

\modules\smath\toolbar\The "math" toolbar I made is placed here.

\modules\dbapp\toolbar\The "base" toolbar I made is placed here.
```

Backup file, when reinstalling, put the file in the original place.

> **Note:**
>
> 1. Because of the toolbar that I made myself, default file name, will automatically use Numbering, so to open the file, can know the name of
>      the toolbar.
> 2. The front file name "custom_toolbar_" cannot be changed, change will cause error, behind's file name can be changed.    For example:
>      custom_toolbar_c01611ed.xml→custom_toolbar_AAA.xml.
> 3. Do well of toolbar, can be copied to other places to use.    For example: In the "writer" Do well of toolbar, can be copied to "calc"
>      places to use.

LibreOffice self-made symbol toolbar

> **Step 1**  Start "Recording Macros function" Tools\Options\Advanced\Enable macro recording（Tick）, in the
>   "Tools\Macros", the "Record Macro" option will appear.
>
> **Step 2**  Recording Macros Tools\Macros\Record Macro→Recording action (click "Ω" to enter symbol→select symbol→Insert)→Stop
>   Recording→The name Macros stored in "Module1" is Main→Modify Main
>   name→Save.
>
> **Step 3**  Add item new toolbar Tools\Customize\Toolbar→Add→Enter a name (example: symbol)→OK, the new toolbar will appear in the top
>   left.
>
> **Step 4**  Will Macros Add item new toolbar Tools\Customize\Toolbar\Category\Macros\My
>   Macros\Standard\Module1\Main→Click "Main"→Add item→Modify→Rename (can
>   be named with symbol)→OK→OK.

Comment:  please consider revising your post otherwise modes will remove it.

Comment: I do not understand how it is a relevant answer?